# Select.Pdf: security transparent method to access security critical method

Tags: .net, pdf-generation

I am using Select.Pdf to make PDF files of pages of my angular app.

Select.Pdf is ruinning on server side in .Net.Core 4.6.2.

Here is the code which is doing the conversion

```
SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf converter = new SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf();    
SelectPdf.PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(url);
return doc.Save();
```

For some reason ConvertUrl method ends up with the exception listed below

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Conversion failure. Attempt by security transparent method 'SelectPdf.Lib.ស.ᜃ()' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Int32)' failed.

Assembly 'Select.Pdf, Version=18.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e0ae9f6e27a97018' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.
  Source=Select.Pdf
  StackTrace:
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToImage.ᜀ(String A_0, ឨ[]& A_1, ឃ& A_2)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4)
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(String url)
   at Powel.UtilityFlow.Portal.HtmlToPdfService.SelectPdfHtmlToPdfService.GeneratePdf(String url) in C:\Projects\Powel.Dynamics365.Portal\Powel.UtilityFlow.Portal\Services\HtmlToPdfService\SelectPdfHtmlToPdfService.cs:line 41
   at Powel.UtilityFlow.Portal.Controllers.EnquiryController.generatePDF(Guid id, String url) in C:\Projects\Powel.Dynamics365.Portal\Powel.UtilityFlow.Portal\Controllers\EnquiryController.cs:line 435
   at Powel.UtilityFlow.Portal.Controllers.EnquiryController.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<PostNewEnquiry>b__1() in C:\Projects\Powel.Dynamics365.Portal\Powel.UtilityFlow.Portal\Controllers\EnquiryController.cs:line 316
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Does anybody have any clue of what the root cause of this exception could be?

Comment: Same problem. Have you found solution?

Comment: try to restore the Select.pdf package again and see if its clearing the issue